# estimateAffine3D opencv 2.4 CV_ARE_SIZES_EQ(m1, m2) && CV_ARE_SIZES_EQ(m1, mask)

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to use `cv2.estimateAffine3D()` from (opencv 2.4.2) function to estimate the affine 3D transformation between to sets of 3D points.

Here is my code:

```
def computeAffine3d():
    # Init src and dst points to 0 
    src_points = cv2.cv.CreateMat(1, 4, cv2.cv.CV_32FC3)
    dst_points = cv2.cv.CreateMat(1, 4, cv2.cv.CV_32FC3)
    cv2.cv.Zero(src_points)
    cv2.cv.Zero(dst_points)

    # Convert cv Mat to numpy array
    src_points = np.array( src_points )
    dst_points = np.array( dst_points )

    # Set src_points to (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (0,1,0) and (0,0,1)
    # Set dst_points to (1,0,0), (2,0,0), (1,1,0) and (1,0,1) 
    src_points[0][1][0] = 1.0
    src_points[0][2][1] = 1.0
    src_points[0][3][2] = 1.0 
    dst_points[0][0][0] = 1.0
    dst_points[0][1][0] = 2.0
    dst_points[0][2][0] = 1.0
    dst_points[0][2][1] = 1.0
    dst_points[0][3][0] = 1.0
    dst_points[0][3][2] = 1.0

    # Compute Affine 3D tranformation
    ok_flag, H, status1 = cv2.estimateAffine3D(src_points, dst_points)
    print ok_flag, ', ', H, ', ', status1
```

After I execute this piece of code I obtain the following error:

```
cOpenCV Error: Assertion failed (CV_ARE_SIZES_EQ(m1, m2) && CV_ARE_SIZES_EQ(m1, mask)) in runRANSAC, file /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-opencv2-2.4.2-0precise-20120908-1632/modules/calib3d/src/modelest.cpp, line 122
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_affine_estimation.py", line 33, in <module>
    computeAffine3d()
  File "./test_affine_estimation.py", line 25, in computeAffine3d
    ok_flag, H, status1 = cv2.estimateAffine3D(src_points, dst_points)
cv2.error: /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-opencv2-2.4.2-0precise-20120908-1632/modules/calib3d/src/modelest.cpp:122: error: (-215) CV_ARE_SIZES_EQ(m1, m2) && CV_ARE_SIZES_EQ(m1, mask) in function runRANSAC
```

Any idea? 
Thak you!

Comment: This is a known bug: http://code.opencv.org/issues/2375